# Tensorflow.js cubic polynomial approximation

Tags: typescript, tensorflow.js

So I'm trying to get into Tensorflow and wanted to try this [fit-curve tutorial](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/fit-curve.html) in typescript.

I don't see much difference to the docs, but the SGD optimizer in my case seems to oscillate out of number range instead of minimizing? Maybe someone can see the problem immediately...

- Trying lower learningRate certainly doesn't help much
- Using a different optimizer **works** (e.g. replacing .sgd with .adam)

Steps Overview (see bottom of code):

- generate 10 points with x=rand(0..100) for f(x)=1x³+2x²+3x+4
- set rate to .0000001 (would like .5 or higher)
- approximate curve with 1, 5, 10 steps

Console output (x: x, y: y <=> yTrained ==> diff):

```
f(x)=ax³+bx²+cx+d: 1 in 832ms: 23966.115234375, 298.5378112792969, 3.8008997440338135, 0.05001421645283699
    x: 30.47792458272469, y: 30264.304156120106 <=> 678783617.7128912 ==> 678753353.4087352
    x: 80.28933091786573, y: 530712.8901260403 <=> 12406193327.27859 ==> 12405662614.388464
    x: 83.20465291191101, y: 590126.6416137978 <=> 13807196536.914392 ==> 13806606410.27278
    x: 4.705203030318961, y: 166.5616668725893 <=> 2503134.008839548 ==> 2502967.4471726753
    x: 51.6146399264698, y: 142992.0542581485 <=> 3296257832.6580544 ==> 3296114840.603796
    x: 63.04112413466787, y: 258678.4748135199 <=> 6005584931.290034 ==> 6005326252.815221
    x: 87.3460615554209, y: 681917.0253005795 <=> 15973113065.600096 ==> 15972431148.574795
    x: 37.19785928759356, y: 54352.916350066305 <=> 1233948246.1033068 ==> 1233893893.1869566
    x: 58.41298898556424, y: 206313.02623606965 <=> 4777696480.876462 ==> 4777490167.850225
    x: 16.60852306193672, y: 5186.8571088452845 <=> 109879466.05047359 ==> 109874279.19336474
f(x)=ax³+bx²+cx+d: 5 in 740ms: 7.155174409828215e+21, 89080444165388500000, 1133177711745826800, 14889370641235968
    x: 30.47792458272469, y: 30264.304156120106 <=> 2.0265337241494757e+26 ==> 2.0265337241494757e+26
    x: 80.28933091786573, y: 530712.8901260403 <=> 3.7039156556767173e+27 ==> 3.7039156556767173e+27
    x: 83.20465291191101, y: 590126.6416137978 <=> 4.1221904429790747e+27 ==> 4.1221904429790747e+27
    x: 4.705203030318961, y: 166.5616668725893 <=> 7.473190365025798e+23 ==> 7.473190365025798e+23
    x: 51.6146399264698, y: 142992.0542581485 <=> 9.841101205493355e+26 ==> 9.841101205493355e+26
    x: 63.04112413466787, y: 258678.4748135199 <=> 1.7929899156585234e+27 ==> 1.7929899156585234e+27
    x: 87.3460615554209, y: 681917.0253005795 <=> 4.76883298542593e+27 ==> 4.76883298542593e+27
    x: 37.19785928759356, y: 54352.916350066305 <=> 3.683998510372637e+26 ==> 3.683998510372637e+26
    x: 58.41298898556424, y: 206313.02623606965 <=> 1.4263991991276407e+27 ==> 1.4263991991276407e+27
    x: 16.60852306193672, y: 5186.8571088452845 <=> 3.2804916875550836e+25 ==> 3.2804916875550836e+25
f(x)=ax³+bx²+cx+d: 10 in 819ms: NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN
    x: 30.47792458272469, y: 30264.304156120106 <=> NaN ==> NaN
    x: 80.28933091786573, y: 530712.8901260403 <=> NaN ==> NaN
    x: 83.20465291191101, y: 590126.6416137978 <=> NaN ==> NaN
    x: 4.705203030318961, y: 166.5616668725893 <=> NaN ==> NaN
    x: 51.6146399264698, y: 142992.0542581485 <=> NaN ==> NaN
    x: 63.04112413466787, y: 258678.4748135199 <=> NaN ==> NaN
    x: 87.3460615554209, y: 681917.0253005795 <=> NaN ==> NaN
    x: 37.19785928759356, y: 54352.916350066305 <=> NaN ==> NaN
    x: 58.41298898556424, y: 206313.02623606965 <=> NaN ==> NaN
    x: 16.60852306193672, y: 5186.8571088452845 <=> NaN ==> NaN
```

Source Code:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

const arrayFrom = (len: number) => Array.from(Array(Math.max(len || 0, 0)).keys());

/** Detect a b c d for ax³+bx²+cx+d */
async function detectCubicPolynom({ xyFlatData = <number[]>[], loops = 100, learningRate = .01 }) {
  // VARIABLES: init with 0
  const [aa, bb, cc, dd] = arrayFrom(4).map(ii => tf.variable(tf.scalar(0)));

  // MODEL: f(x)=ax³+bx²+cx+d
  const doPredict = (xs: tf.Tensor) => tf.tidy(() =>
    aa.mul(xs.pow(tf.scalar(3)))
      .add(bb.mul(xs.square()))
      .add(cc.mul(xs))
      .add(dd)
  );

  // LOSS FUNCTION: MSE (mean squared error) i.e. mean of square of diff
  const doLoss = (predictions: tf.Tensor, labels: tf.Tensor) => tf.tidy(() => predictions.sub(labels).square().mean());

  // OPTIMIZER - SGD (stochastic gradient descent)
  const optimizer = tf.train.sgd(learningRate);

  // TRAIN
  const doTrain = (xs: tf.Tensor, ys: tf.Tensor) => tf.tidy(() =>
    optimizer.minimize(() => <tf.Tensor<tf.Rank.R0>>doLoss(doPredict(xs), ys)));
  const doTrainTimes = (xs: tf.Tensor, ys: tf.Tensor, times: number) =>
    arrayFrom(times).map(ii => doTrain(xs, ys)).filter(ii => !!ii).forEach(ii => ii.dispose());

  // EXECUTE
  const xData = tf.tensor1d(xyFlatData.filter((ii, index) => index % 2 === 0));
  const yData = tf.tensor1d(xyFlatData.filter((ii, index) => index % 2 !== 0));
  if (xyFlatData.length > 0 && loops > 0) {
    doTrainTimes(xData, yData, loops);
  }

  // RESULT
  const result = (await Promise.all([aa, bb, cc, dd].map(ii => ii.data())))
    .reduce((acc, ii) => acc.concat([...ii]), <number[]>[]);

  // CLEANUP
  [aa, bb, cc, dd, xData, yData].forEach(ii => ii.dispose());

  return result;
}

const tryDetectCubicPolynom = (xyFlatData: number[], loops: number, learningRate: number) => {
  const now = Date.now();
  detectCubicPolynom({ xyFlatData: xyFlatData || [], loops: Math.max(loops || 0, 1), learningRate: learningRate || .5 })
    .then(abcd => {
      console.log(`f(x)=ax³+bx²+cx+d: ${loops} in ${Date.now() - now}ms: ${abcd.join(', ')}`);
      for (let ii = 0; ii < xyFlatData.length; ii += 2) {
        const x = xyFlatData[ii];
        const y = xyFlatData[ii + 1];
        const yTrained = abcd[0] * x ** 3 + abcd[1] * x ** 2 + abcd[2] * x + abcd[3];
        console.log(`\tx: ${x}, y: ${y} <=> ${yTrained} ==> ${Math.abs(yTrained - y)}`);
      }
    });
}

const generatePolynomialPoints = (weights: number[], points: number, xUntil = 10) => {
  const flatPoints = Array<number>(points * 2);
  for (let ii = 0; ii < points; ++ii) {
    const xx = Math.random() * 100;
    const yy = weights.reduce((acc, val, index) => acc + val * xx ** (weights.length - 1 - index), 0);
    flatPoints[2 * ii] = xx;
    flatPoints[2 * ii + 1] = yy;
  }
  return flatPoints;
}

const generatedPoints = generatePolynomialPoints([1, 2, 3, 4], 10, 100);
const rate = .0000001;
tryDetectCubicPolynom(generatedPoints, 1, rate);
tryDetectCubicPolynom(generatedPoints, 5, rate);
tryDetectCubicPolynom(generatedPoints, 10, rate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should normalize the values of X's between 0 and 1 before training a model for numerical stability. (See: https://www.coursera.org/learn/deep-neural-network/lecture/lXv6U/normalizing-inputs for more detail)

For this example, you can simply limit the range of X's randomly generated, and it should work. Note in the tutorial, how the values of X's lie between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing, was wondering why it oscillates completely out of control using the SGD optimizer and meanSquareError for the loss function, so to debug it I lowered the learning rate to something suuuuper small and guess what? That worked... I'm using a learning rate of 0.000000000001 right now. Why do they use 0.5 in their example and why does it seem to work for them? I have no idea. So try adding a few more zeroes until it works. If anyone knows why it has to be this small when the official example uses 0.5, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

@TaVirot and @Hans 's anwser make some points. Their answer can be ways to solve it. 
A cause of the issue is some data points has much significant effect on gradients than others. For example, when

```
x=100
```

and

```
a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4
```

then

```
f(x)=f(100) = 1*100^3+2*100^2+3*100+4 = 1020304.
```

And assume `a` changes to 1.1, then `f(100) = 1120304`. Difference is **100,000**.

Otherwise, when `x=1` and `a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4`, then

```
f(x)=f(1) = 1*1^3+2*1^2+3*1^1+4 = 10
```

And assume `a` changes to 1.1, then `f(1) = 10.1`. In this case, difference is **0.1**.

So same weight change eventually invoke enormous f(x) difference depending on **x value**. So, if you use just **Mean square error** as cost function, this **x=100 point** casue huge gradients in backpropagation. In conclusion, to avoid model divergence, please consider low learning rates or normalization of data or another cost function. (Maybe there are some other ways.)